# jquery function onclick and onload myFunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have an .on(click) where an ajax call happens now the problem is I want everything in the .on(click) to happen also when the pages loads.
My plan is to create a function and put everything that happens in the .on(click) in this function. And when the pages loads I want this function to trigger too.

Here's what I've tried but doesn't seem to be working.

my .on(click):

```
$('.changetypevastgoed').on('click', function(e){
    var termid = $(this).data('termid');
    $('#slctypevastgoed').val(termid);
    $('#vastgoedtypes').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: "termid=" + termid,
    url: $('body').data('theme-url') + '/lib/getsearchoptions.php',
    success: function(result) {
        var juistekeyslanden=[];
        $.each(result.landen, function(key1, value1) {
            $.each(value1, function(key2, value2) {
                if (key2 == termid){
                    juistekeyslanden.push(key1);
                }
            });
        });

        $('select#land').find('option').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            var currentoption = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if ($.inArray(currentoption, juistekeyslanden) != -1){
                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            }
        }).after(function( x ) {
          $('.chosen').trigger('chosen:updated');
        });

        var juistekeysoppervlakten=[];
        $.each(result.oppervlakten, function(key1, value1) {
            $.each(value1, function(key2, value2) {
                if (key2 == termid){
                    juistekeysoppervlakten.push(key1);
                }
            });
        });
        $('select#oppervlakte').find('option').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            var currentoption = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if ($.inArray(currentoption, juistekeysoppervlakten) != -1){
                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            }
        }).after(function( x ) {
          $('.chosen').trigger('chosen:updated');
        });

        var juistekeyspostocodes=[];
        $.each(result.postcodes, function(key1, value1) {
            $.each(value1, function(key2, value2) {
                if (key2 == termid){
                    juistekeyspostocodes.push(key1);
                }
            });
        });
        $('select#postcode').find('option').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            var currentoption = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if ($.inArray(currentoption, juistekeyspostocodes) != -1){
                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            }
        }).after(function( x ) {
          $('.chosen').trigger('chosen:updated');
        });
        }
    });//success
});
```

So I've tried putting my AJAX call in a function like so:

```
$.fn.myfunction = function () {
        $.ajax({
            ...
};
```

I set this right under my

> jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

And in my on.click I do this:

> $('.changetypevastgoed').myFunction();

On this line I get this error

> $(...).myFunction is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".changetypevastgoed").trigger("click");
});
```

have u tried something like this ?

Comment: I've tried this, but the click doesn't seem to be happening

Comment: If I place trigger event under my original .on(click) it works but 3 clicks happen at page load

Comment: why dont u write a function  and call it for another two ones,u should do first one with trigger and call another second as function if first u want occured than call third fucntion if your second occured

Comment: I fixed it and it works like a charm with this method